# Guidelines for GIS Application Testing

Tags: testing, gis, performance-testing, esri, gui-testing

I am a software tester by profession and I have worked on various technologies till date. I got a new assignment which is a GIS application. I am not aware of how to test GIS application, what parameters should be considered while testing etc. 
I will really appreciate if anyone could help me out with some guidelines for testing GIS application.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You can try to ask at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're pushing out OGC web services (WMS/WFS/WCS etc) then there are validators available: http://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/

Answer (score 1):

Ashok, possibly since the time whn the question has been asked you have been turned into GIS testing expert, but let me try to answer )))

I would focus on what the app should do with geometries:

1. does it takes into account the correct type of geometries, does it ignore the incorrect ones
2. If the app builds own geometries based on the original geometries, I would try different topologies that may be problematic for doing this. Say, the app should draw a geometry 5 px left to some original geometry, in parallel to it. I would try a loop that is lesser than 10 px diameter in order to have no space to 5 px left. And so on
3. I would test the huge values of data, so what will be if the app would try to consume the worldwide net of such geometries.